# position: absolute menu stuck at top of body, not in viewport

Tags: css, css-position

My menu is a full-page overlay, using

```
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
```

The relatively-positioned parent is body. This works perfectly when you're at the top of the page, but when you scroll down a bit, it's no good... it's attached at the top of the page. I need to attach it to the viewport somehow, so it's always exactly filling the screen no matter how long the page is.

I don't know how to attach it to the viewport. Can you help?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] in order to assist. That means including the selector (the bit outside of the `{ }` brackets) as well as your HTML.

Comment: you need fixed not absolute

Comment: Thanks, Temani. That did it. I appreciate your help!